# Laravel 7 Ajax Datatables get data update

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, datatables

I have a problem that make me stuck for a couple days.
I use laravel 7 and jax, and yajra datatables and i want to make page edit which show data by id from database.
before this i use popup modal to create and edit data, but for this i want to make another page for create and edit, so i would direct to another page like this
"/pegawai/edit/{{ $p->pegawai_id }}". so when i click button edit there are direct to page edit.
for page create and function delete is ok, but i stuck at edit.

this my controller to get list

```
public function getList(Request $request){
    $data = Cms::all();
    $canEdit = Auth::user()->can($this->permissions["edit"]);
    $canDelete = Auth::user()->can($this->permissions["delete"]);
    return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row)use($canEdit,$canDelete){
                $btn = '';
                $canEdit ? $btn .= "<a href='/console/cms/editData'>
                <button 
                type = 'button' 
                class = 'btn btn-warning btn-sm'
                onclick = 'editData(this)'
                idData = '".$row->id."'
                title = '".$row->title."'
                slug = '".$row->slug."'
                meta_title = '".$row->meta_title."'
                meta_desc = '".$row->meta_desc."'
                description = '".$row->description."'
                >Edit</button></a>":'';
                
                
                $canDelete ? $btn .= '<button 
                type = "button" 
                class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                onclick = "deleteData(this)" 
                idData = "'.$row->id.'" 
                >Delete</button>
                ':"";
                return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
}
```

this function at blade

```
function editData(attribute){
    resetError();
    resetForm();

    var id = $(attribute).attr('idData');
    var title = $(attribute).attr('title');
    var slug = $(attribute).attr('slug');
    var meta_title = $(attribute).attr('meta_title');
    var meta_desc = $(attribute).attr('meta_desc');
    var content = $(attribute).attr('description');
    tinymce.get("description").setContent(content);
    var cms_file = $(attribute).attr('cms_file');

    $("#id").val(id);
    $("#title").val(title);
    $("#slug").val(slug);
    $("#meta_title").val(meta_title);
    $("#meta_desc").val(meta_desc);
    $('#description').val(description);
    $('#cms_file').val(cms_file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
$canEdit ? $btn .= "<a href='/pegawai/edit/".rawurlencode($row->id)."' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>Edit</a>";
```

Comment: i have solve this issue with this $canEdit ? $btn .= "<a href='/console/cms/editData/".$row->id."'>. thankyou

Answer (score -1):

if you are using the jquery, you need to add event delegation from the body because the element is coming from ajax. maybe use

```
$('body').on('click','.yourBtnClassname',function(e){


});
```

[see this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOidW.png)

Comment: for post data its success, but my problem is to get data by id to show on edit page

Comment: you need to get the id by using $(this).data('id');